# Вычисление максимально возможного веса людей в лифте

Tags: алгоритм, сложность

Задача похожа на [предыдущий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/807602/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82%D0%B5), только здесь цель другая, изначально задача была неправильно понята. В предыдущей задаче надо было вычислить максимальное количество людей вместимых в лифт, а в этом надо максимально нагрузить лифт. Изначально задача была не правильно понята
Дано список людей с именем и весом, максимальный вес который выдержит лифт. Вычислить максимальный вес которое может поместиться и вывести их список, какие люди поместятся чтобы максимально нагрузить лифт.

Не понимаю как определить комбинацию людей которые могут быть. Ведь может быть разные комбинации, 1, 2, 3 или 1, 2, 4, или 1, 3, 5, 6. Хочу сначала узнать все возможные комбинации вместимых людей и потом выводить максимальное. Но как узнать комбинации этих людей или как по другому решаются такие задачи

```
public class MaxLift {
public static void main(String[] args) {

Man[] men = new Man[10];
men[0] = new Man("0", 110);
men[1] = new Man("1", 30);
men[2] = new Man("2", 34);
men[3] = new Man("3", 67);
men[4] = new Man("4", 33);
men[5] = new Man("5", 65);
men[6] = new Man("6", 19);
men[7] = new Man("7", 80);
men[8] = new Man("8", 98);
men[9] = new Man("9", 45);
int liftMaxWeight = 200;

TreeSet<List<Man>> set = new TreeSet<>();//add comparator
for (int i = 0; i < men.length; i++) {
    List<Man> list  = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add()
}

//sout
}

private static class Man {
String name;
int weight;

public Man(String name, int weight) {
    this.name = name;
    this.weight = weight;
}
 }
 }
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вычисление максимального количества людей в лифте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/807602/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d1%8e%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%82%d0%b5)

Comment: Вам же уже ответили на оба вопроса!

Comment: Просто задача состоит в другом изначально не правильно понял

Comment: А вот это уже классическая [задача о рюкзаке](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5); Здесь полный перебор — одно из валидных (хотя не самых эффективных) решений... ЗЫ: стоило бы вынести отдельным абзацем с заголовком, в чём отличие от предыдущего вопроса...

Comment: Не успел предупредить, хорошо бы пояснить в вопросе почему новый создали, у нас на SO люди любят минусовать за разное и блокировки кидать. Как-то так написать, что тот вопрос был поставлен некорректно и оказалось что задача в другом. Я то понимаю почему создали, а кто новый заходит не в теме ситуации.

Comment: Если чисто по этому вопросу то надо решать через перебор, но можно его ограничить, что бы это был не полный перебор, как именно пока сказать не могу.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин Да классическое ДП. Задача разобрана множество раз.

Comment: Наверняка задание имеет чёткую формулировку. Почему бы не привести её в точности вместо пересказа своими словами?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вычисление максимального возможного веса при заполнении лифта людьми с указанными весами, можно выполнить используя упрощённое решение для [задачи о рюкзаке 0-1](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5#%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%80%D1%8E%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5_0-1) `O(n W)` по времени `O(W)` в памяти решение (`n` - количество людей, `W` - грузоподъёмность), на Питоне:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Find max weight given people weights, elevator capacity."""

weights = 110, 30, 34, 67, 33, 65, 19, 80, 98, 45
capacity = 200

# m[c] — max possible weight using items seen so far under *c* capacity
m = [0] * (capacity + 1)
prev = m[:]  # previous value (without the current item)
for w in weights:
    for c in range(capacity + 1):
        m[c] = prev[c] if w > c else max(prev[c], prev[c-w] + w)
    prev, m = m, prev
print('Max weight:', prev[-1])
```

Вывод: `Max weight: 200` (можно заполнить до максимальной нагрузки). Что совпадает с ответом, получаемым [адаптацией более общего решения](https://repl.it/@zed1/knapsack-0-1-weight) из вопроса [Задача о рюкзаке (ранце) python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/673495/23044).

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/brython-dev/brython/3.4.0/www/src/brython.js"></script><body onload="brython()"><script type="text/python">
import json
from browser import document

def max_weight(weights, capacity):
    m = [0] * (capacity + 1)
    prev = m[:]  # previous value (without the current item)
    for w in weights:
        for c in range(capacity + 1):
            m[c] = prev[c] if w > c else max(prev[c], prev[c-w] + w)
        prev, m = m, prev
    return prev[-1]

@document["mybutton"].bind("click") 
def on_click(event=None):
    capacity = int(document["capacity"].value)
    weights = json.loads(document["json"].value)
    print(f"{capacity}, {weights} -> {max_weight(weights, capacity)}")
on_click('dummy on start')
</script><label for="json">Weights: </label><input id="json", value="[110, 30, 34, 67, 33, 65, 19, 80, 98, 45]"> <label for="capacity">Max&nbsp;weight: <input id="capacity" value="200"> <button id="mybutton">Запустить</button></body>
```

Comment: В задаче нужно вычислить список людей

Comment: 1- нажмите на ссылку в ответе, где представлено более общее решение -- оно возвращает кто был выбран 2- заголовок вопроса явно говорит: найти *максимальный вес*, а не список людей.

Comment: Да, прошу прощения, заголовок не правильный(

Comment: @AlexanderBelov по ссылкам в ответе есть пошаговое словесное описание алгоритма в другом моём ответе и псевдо-код на Википедия страничке (из которого Питон-код был написан). Данный алгоритм на Java нормально должен выражаться (несколько простых циклов с использованием массивов).

Comment: Я решаю с перерывом, все еще нет времени полностью сесть, не подумайте что до сих пор решаю, хотя признаю что задача очень сложная

Comment: Если наибольшая ценность, которую можно получить, используя все доступные предметы (индексы не более заданного), больше ценности, которую можно получить, не включая текущий предмет (с наибольшим индексом), то
добавляем текущий предмет в результат, 
не могу понять что вы имеете ввиду, все предметы включая и исключая только текущий с наибольшим индексом - это значит индекс в массиве, как это связано

Comment: @AlexanderBelov: я не вижу слово "ценность" в данном ответе. Вы похоже к другому ответу хотели комментарий оставить.

Comment: что значит O(n W) по времени, это умножение или сложение

Comment: @AlexanderBelov умножение

Answer (score 2):

Я вижу такое решение:

Сначала отсортировать массив людей начиная от больших к меньшим.

Перебирать методом который в [прошлом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/807602/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82%D0%B5) сказал Harry, сначала беря `00000` потом `10000` `01000` `11000` `00100` `10100` и так далее.

Суммирование начинаем слева направо, если сумма превысила предел то прекращаем перебор по всей ветке, со всеми числами далее.

То есть если есть вариант [abcdef]ghij и сумма [abcdef] уже больше предела, то остаток [ghij] уже перебирать смысла нету, и эту часть пропускаем.

Сортировка от большего к меньшим позволит отбросить максимальное число вариантов, так как лишняя концовка состоящая из наименьших чисел будет максимальна по длине, и значит наибольшее количество вариантов отбросится, по сравнению с любым другим видом сортировки.

Comment: То есть если есть вариант [abcdefghij и сумма [abcdef] уже больше предела, то остаток [ghij] уже перебирать смысла нету, и эту часть пропускаем. Не понимаю, ведь если сумма [abcdef] больше можно же попробовать вместо f прибавить g, потому что g меньше f, соответственно может не привысить

Comment: @AlexanderBelov это да, я имею ввиду что варианты с [abcdef]xxxx где разные xxxx уже не надо подбирать, а [fbcdef] фиксированы.